# Listen to Serial over TCP/IP Port C# ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port

I'm developing a weather site, with several weather stations. Ever station uses a different method to post data to the server. They all work, except one. It's a brand new station, but uses a serial port. The company that installed the station connected the station to a Moxa Serial converter. Witch essentially sends the serial data over a specific TCP port to my remote server. Using Pccomm Terminal Emilator I can receive the data on my server. But how should I get my app to listen to this port for serial data. I tried Tcplistener, but it doesn't receive any data. Data is in NMEA format.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics I can only give you some general hints, but here goes:

Many Serial-to-Ethernet converters include server-side software that will make the data appear on a virtual serial port.  If that is the case, with the software installed you will see the virtual port listed along with the real ports in your system. You can simply open and read from that port as usual.

If that is not the case, but you are receiving data on a known TCP port and can view it using Telnet or something similar, then perhaps the Moxa converter is acting as a server and expects you to be the client. In that case you would want to use the **TCPClient** class rather than the **TCPListener** class.

The Moxa converter (you didn't give the model number) has a manual which may prove helpful.

If you need more help then you will need to post specifics about exactly how you are connecting with PComm and what you see, and exactly what you tried with TCPListener, and what happened.

gl